# Run terminal commands from GUI app?

Tags: c, macos, terminal, task

Do you guys know how to run terminal commands from you GUI application? I need the coding for my app. For example, if I type "netstat" in terminal it will give me all the ports. I want to this from my xcode app. Is that possible? BTW it's not just the "netstat" command it could be "sudo.... "

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code I just cut out of one on my apps that uses NSTask.

```
NSTask* task = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/java"];

NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-jar", jar, @"--cue", inp, @"--dir", dir, mp3, nil];
[task setArguments: args];

taskOutputFile = [[self createTmpFile] retain];
NSFileHandle* taskOutput = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:taskOutputFile];

[task setStandardOutput: taskOutput];
[task launch];
```

This launches an app (java) and records the output in a temp file

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to drop down to C, you could just use the `system()` function. Of course, this will print the results of the command. If you want to store the results of the command, you'll probably want to use a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a more Cocoa-like way of doing this.